# Linux Mint Debian dual boot windows on second harddrive

Tags: linux, grub

i have a grub problem.
I got Linux on /dev/sdb and Windows 10 on /dev/sdd.

Looks like:

```
sdb      8:16   0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   1,9G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 109,9G  0 part / 
sdd      8:48   0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   0   549M  0 part 
└─sdd2   8:50   0 111,3G  0 part
```

On sdd2 there is `Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi` and `Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgr.efi`.

I can't get my custom grub config working. 
I want a grub menu with option Linux Mint and with option Windows 10.

Any idea's? Thank you in advanced!!

Paul

Comment: Ir's a UEFI system, install all OSes in that mode. Only one EFI partition is needed and recommended. It doesn't matter Mint or other installed in a different physical drive.

Comment: So i need to install Mint in UEFI mode?

Comment: You don't *need* but you *should*, for a variety of reasons, not the least of them being it makes multiple boot a lot easier and safer to manage.

Comment: So there is a other possibility to manage the multiple boot?

Comment: There is but the rule is the same: Always install all OSes in the same mode.